# Counting Duplicate Values for a CASE statement

Tags: sql, hive

In my query, I have a CASE statement where I want to cast the column as string value if condition matches. Also, I want to know the total number of duplicated values for that CASE statement's result.
For example:

```
select NULL as column_1,
   CASE WHEN name IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(name as string)
   ELSE '0' END as column_2,
    (select COUNT (cast(column_2 as string)) from input_table
     group by (cast(column_2 as string)) HAVING count(cast(column_2 as string)) > 1) as column_3
    from input_table
```

Can I go for CASE statement and counting the condition output at the same time?
 Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CTE here. Not 100% clear on what your looking for but try this.

```
;WITH Input_table as (

SELECT NULL AS column_1,
       CASE
           WHEN name IS NOT NULL
           THEN CAST(name AS STRING)
           ELSE '0'
       END AS column_2
)

select distinct Column_1, Column_2, count(Column_2) [Cnt] from Input_table
group by Column_1, Column_2 
having count(Column_2) > 1
```